# Android ,thread id=1 thread exiting with uncaught exception

Tags: java, android, multithreading, uncaught-exception

I am new to android development, was following a tutorial in order to get a better understanding about fragments, but after completing the tutorial when it comes to testing I encountered this particular problem after removing a few syntax errors. In the logcat I get "**threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a7193**" I've spent almost an entire working day on it, I've looked but it seems like the solution to this problem is dependent upon the source code, I've been on a number of links but everywhere there's some source code provided and I haven't found a solution for my problem so far, any help will be much appreciated.  Here is My Code:

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.fragmentsexample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ToolbarFragments.ToolbarListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onButtonClick(int fontsize, String text) {
        TextFragment textFragment = 
                (TextFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.text_fragment);        
        textFragment.changeTextProperties(fontsize, text);
    }
}
```

Here is TextFragment.java:

```
package com.example.fragmentsexample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TextFragment extends Fragment {

    private static TextView textview;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.text_fragment, container,false);
        textview=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        return view;
    }

    public void changeTextProperties(int fontsize, String text){
        textview.setTextSize(fontsize);
        textview.setText(text);
    }
}
```

Here is ToolbarFragments.java

```
package com.example.fragmentsexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;

public class ToolbarFragments extends Fragment {

    private static int seekvalue=10;
    private static EditText editText;

    ToolbarListener activityCallback;

    public interface ToolbarListener {
        public void onButtonClick(int position, String text);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity){
        super.onAttach(activity);

        try{
            activityCallback=(ToolbarListener) activity;
        }       
        catch (Exception e){
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()+ "must implement ToolbarListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle SavedInstanceState){
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.toolbar_fragment, container, false);

        editText=(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        final SeekBar seekbar=(SeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener((OnSeekBarChangeListener) this);
        final Button button=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {      
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                buttonClicked(v);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    public void buttonClicked(View v){
        activityCallback.onButtonClick(seekvalue,editText.getText().toString());    
    }

    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser){
        seekvalue=progress;
    }

    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Here is the activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_fragment"
    android:name="com.example.fragmentexample.ToolbarFragments"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    tools:layout="@layout/toolbar_fragment" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/text_fragment"
    android:name="com.example.fragmentexample.TextFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    tools:layout="@layout/text_fragment" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the text_fragment.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:layout_centerVertical="true"
       android:text="@string/fragtwo"
       android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />   
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the toolbar_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:text="@string/button"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="text" >
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help any sort of help will be appreciated it is my second post here i apologize for a messy post

Comment: Where is the stack trace? What is the full message of Logcat?

Comment: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)

Comment: also when i select error rather than warn this is the description "FATAL EXCEPTION: main"

Comment: where as on console theres no error but the notification that the application is successfully installed on the emulator

Comment: Show the log cat details.

Comment: anything else u need please let me know

Comment: You cannot just cut one piece of the log and then expect to have the community to guess the rest. Please post full log in order to get help. Also, it is better if you update the question rather than positing updates in the comments. Another tip to move forward it to debug your code and step through to see where this happens. The error specified is typically that there is an error in your code that you simply ignore and if you step through the code you will be able to see where this happens, if you think the log is to complicated to read.